# Windows service is not starting

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services

i used c# to create Windows service but after installing , it doesn't work 
and it shows nothing in log so i don't understand the error to solve it 
.[image: Error which is appeared]

this is my on-start event

```
     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            StartSynchro();
        }
        public void StartSynchro()
        {
            while (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

            }
            GoogleDriveHandler driveHandler = new GoogleDriveHandler();
            List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> onlineFiles = driveHandler.getFiles();
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File onlineVerCSVFile = onlineFiles.Where(c => c.Name == GoogleDriveHandler.onlineVerCSV).First();
            onlineFiles.Remove(onlineVerCSVFile);
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result = Helper.ReadFromMemoryStream(driveHandler.downloadfile_GetStream(ref onlineVerCSVFile));
            List<string> corspondingVer = new List<string>();
            foreach (var onlineFile in onlineFiles)
            {
                corspondingVer.Add(result.Find(c => c.Key == onlineFile.Name).Value);
            }

            List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> fileToDownload = LocalClasses.LocalFilesInfo.getFilesToDwonload(onlineFiles, corspondingVer, ref driveHandler);
            driveHandler.StartDownloading(fileToDownload);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: How does you OnStart override look like?

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for any exception details.

Comment: @AlexK. what do  you mean by event Viewer ?

Comment: @DanielFuchs check again the question , i wrote OnStart override event.

Comment: windows key+r and run eventvwr.msc

Comment: Could it be that you just hang in the while loop?

Comment: When you start a service, **the OnStart method must return within a short timeout so the SCM knows the service was started successfully**. However you are doing synchronous work in the OnStart method, which resumably is taking longer than the (default) 60 seconds the SCM allows. Easiest way would be to call `StartSynchro()` on another thread.

Comment: @AlexK. 
It says :Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to start the windows service as fast as possible. You could move the initialization code to a separate thread as follows:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   Task.Run(() => StartSynchro());
}
```

Comment: good but i have other problem ,how can i create directory to user documents in this windows service ?

Comment: you should be able to do it once you start the windows service with admin privileges!